# Fontsize of attributedString doesn't change

Tags: swift, font-size, nsattributedstring

I have an `attributedString` and want to change only it's fontsize. To do that, I use another method that I found on StackOverflow. For most cases, this is working, but somehow it doesn't change the whole `attributedString` in one case.

Method to change the size:

```
/**
*A struct with static methods that can be useful for your GUI
*/
struct GuiUtils {

static func setAttributedStringToSize(attributedString: NSAttributedString, size: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let mus = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    mus.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: mus.string.count)) { (value, range, stop) in
        if let oldFont = value as? UIFont {
            let newFont = oldFont.withSize(size)
            mus.addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    return mus
  }
}
```

Working:

```
    label.attributedText = GuiUtils.setAttributedStringToSize(attributedString: attributedString, size: fontSize)
```

Not working:

```
    mutableAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: gapRange, with: filledGap)
    label.attributedText = GuiUtils.setAttributedStringToSize(attributedString: mutableAttributedString.replaceCharacters, size: fontSize)
```

Somehow, the replaced text does not change its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, but do you sure that your `filledGap` attributed string has `font` attribute? Because if it doesn't – this part will not be handled by the `enumerateAttribute` block.

In this case your fix will be just to set any font to the whole `filledGap` string, to be sure that it's part will be handled by the `enumerateAttribute` block.